# CA2202 on FileStream with StreamWriter

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter, ca2202

I am using a filestream and streamwriter to write a small text on file it giving me CA2202 warning

```
    public void WritePIDToFile()
    {
        FileStream fh = null;
        try
        {
            fh = new FileStream(HIMSHelper.ApplicationDirectory + "PID", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
            using (var sr = new StreamWriter(fh))
            {
                sr.Write(PID);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fh != null)
            {
                fh.Dispose();//I got CA2202 here
            }
        }
    }
```

I already try the solution here [CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx)

Can you give me any suggestions? Please.

Thanks

Comment: Your `using` block will close the `StreamWriter`, and that may be closing the `FileStream` object as well.  Even if the code errors out in the `using` block, the object(s) will still be closed and disposed.

Comment: "I already try the solution here" -- Not exactly: the `fh = null;` line is missing in your code.

Comment: yeah setting fh = null before calling sr.Write() solve the problem, but i am little worried that it could give an inconsistent behavior. does it?

Comment: What possible inconsistencies are you thinking about? I ask because I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Is it ok to set the fh = null before calling sr.Write(PID)?

Comment: Yes, that's okay. `sr.Write(PID)` doesn't look at the current value of the `fh` variable. It can't, it has no access to it. You passed in the old value with `var sr = new StreamWriter(fh)`, and that old value will be used by `sr.Write(PID)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats a great help.